# When is the function identically 1 in the reduced group $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, completely-positive-maps

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, and consider the reduced group $C_\lambda^* $-algebra $C^* (\Gamma)$. Let $1 \in \ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ be the function which is identically 1 on $\Gamma$.

My question is when does $1 \in C_\lambda^* (G)$, in the sense that there exist $f_n \in C_c(\Gamma)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow 1$ in the reduced norm, that is
$$
\|1-f_n\|_\lambda \rightarrow 0.
$$

I thought about approximation properties, such as amenability, weak amenability, rapid decay property but none of them speak of convergence in the reduced norm.

Comment: I think it may occur only when $\Gamma$ is compact, i.e. finite. For example if $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$ then $C_\lambda^*(\Gamma)$ is identified with $C(\mathbb{T}).$ There is no element $ g\in C(\mathbb{T})$ such that $fg=m(f)g$ for a linear functional $f\mapsto m(f).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\in C_c(\Gamma).$ Then
$$\|f\|_2=\|f*\delta_e\|_2\le \|f\|_\lambda\|\delta_e\|_2=\|f\|_\lambda$$ Hence  if $f_n\in C_c(\Gamma)$ is convergent in $C_\lambda(\Gamma)$ then it is convergent in $\ell^2(\Gamma).$ Therefore $f_n\to {\bf 1}$ implies ${\bf 1}\in \ell^2(\Gamma),$ i.e. $\Gamma$ must be finite.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you very much.